# get checkbox , textbox , button names or id s from events in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get id or name of for example checkbox from event in a windows form application in c#. Is it possible ? 
Thank you..

```
    private void aktifMWcheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cbname = sender.Name; // is it possible something like that ???
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for controls' events you can always cast `sender` to `Control` (because every control inherits from it):

```
var ctrl = (Control)sender;
string cbname = ctrl.Name;
```

Also, if you are sure that is for example a `CheckBox` event, you can cast to it:

```
var ctrl = (CheckBox)sender;
string cbname = ctrl.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a direct cast on the sender.  Something like:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
string cbname = cb.Name;
```

More examples/information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast the sender to the Control class and access
properties for the object such as Name.